# Game State Management Android?

Tags: android

In Windows phone, I found a very useful sample code for Game State Management http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/game_state_management. It contains a skeleton with some basic screen such as: main menu, game play screen, option screen...

Is there any similar sample code in Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a few open source framework that ease the work by providing easy ways to create menus/features/displays.

A few well-known : AndEngine, rokon or libgdx.

Just google "Android game frameworks" and pick one. Just be careful of the licences, there a few non-free frameworks. Well free to use, but you need to pay if you want to distribute/sell your app.